# Button: problems with color and margins around it

Tags: android, user-interface, button, margins

What I am trying to do is a simple UI layout with three items stacked vertically: a TextView, another TextView below it, and a Button below it. Here's the XML (section) that describes this UI:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:background="@color/red">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/updates_pane_title"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/updates_pane_description"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:background="@color/blue"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

    <Button
         android:id="@+id/updates_pane_button"
         android:layout_width="match_parent"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:backgroundTint="@color/black"
         android:text="@string/install"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

(note the RED background of the top LinearLayout and the BLUE background of the middle TextView - that's just for debugging, so I can see where each widget exactly spans to)

When inflated like this, the Layout ends up looking like so:

[image]

Note the red strips below and above the black button. I don't want those margins, I want the button to span the whole available height and touch the blue section in the middle.

Even more curiously, when I try to change the background drawable of the Button (guessing that maybe the default one has some kind of default margins in the top and bottom) in the code like so

```
Button button = view.findViewById(R.id.updates_pane_button);
Drawable draw = act.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.black_button);
button.setBackground(draw);
```

where 'black_button' is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
  <item>
    <shape android:shape="rectangle">
        <solid android:color="@android:color/black"/>
    </shape>
  </item>
</layer-list>
```

then the whole thing ends up looking like this:

[image]

Notice that the red strip margins disappeared (good!), but the whole button turned violet. What??
I have no idea where this violet color comes from. What I want is something that looks like the last picture (without the red/blue debugging, of course), but the button has to stay black.

Comment: Did you try setting "layout_height" of the button to "match_parent"? Also, you can set the background to a drawable via xml too:
    android:background="@drawable/black_button"

Answer (score 0):

I have just figured this out. The culprits were the 'insetTop' - 'insetBottom' properties of the default style. Adding those to XML:

```
<Button
     android:id="@+id/updates_pane_button"
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:backgroundTint="@color/black"
     android:text="@string/install"
     android:insetTop="0dp"
     android:insetBottom="0dp"/>
```

solves the issue with the unexpected margins. I still don't know why the violet color though.